# Is there any difference between to be late and being late in complex object?

Tags: difference, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> He doesn’t like us **to be late** for work.
>
> He doesn't like us **being late** for work.

Is there any difference in meaning between the two?

I know that there is a big difference in meaning between:

> I saw her **open** the window **and** I saw her **opening** the window.

Answer (score 1):

The sense is exactly the same in both sentences, just using [different grammatical devices](https://www.thoughtco.com/identifying-verbals-in-english-grammar-1689699).

Your second examples, "I saw her open the window," and "I saw her opening the window," do **not** have greatly different meanings. Perhaps you meant, "I saw her [while i was] opening the window?"

Comment: I meant "I saw her [while she was] opening the window." I trust English allows some degree of ambiguity here.

Comment: Then what do you believe is the difference in meaning?

Comment: Well, when I say "I saw her opening the window" I emphasize the process of her extending her arms to open the window (I can't be sure if she managed to open it, maybe she was distracted and didn't complete her action), but when I say "I saw her open the window" I just state the fact that she opened it, the window was open in the end by her.

Comment: If she is opening it, continuous tense, she succeeded.